# Which statistical test to use for multiple IV's and DV's

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, multivariate-regression

I am conducting a study over post-concussive symptoms. I have two groups, a non-concussed group and a group who has been concussed. I will have three IV's (depression, anxiety, and neuroticism) and two DV's (number of symptoms endorsed and symptom severity)

I am not that well accustomed to working with multiple IV's and DV's so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you thinking about the multiple DVs? Eg, do you consider them all measures of a single amount of damage from concussions, or do you think of there being independent relationships b/t concussions & each DV?

Comment: I removed the instrumental-variables tag because it was misapplied in the context of this question (see the wiki entry of the instrumental-variables tag whereas here IV refers to explanatory variables)

Comment: Sorry about the accidental tag, Andy!

Comment: Gung - I am thinking of the DV's as being independent from the IV. For example, symptom severity for people who score highly with depression and have not been concussed vs symptom severity for people who score highly with depression but have been concussed.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply multivariate multiple regression or MANCOVA.

MANCOVA is applicable when there are two or more response variables and we want to analyze  the influence of one or more independent variables while removing the effect of one or more covariate factors